# Conditions not working as they should Wix

Tags: wix

I have shortcuts defined like so, I will post two but I have many more:

```
  <!--Shortcuts to be added if variant is not OPC or LOGGER-->
  <Component Id="AlarmShortcut" Guid="1FB13893-5021-4C83-9136-00C89221100B" Directory="ProgramMenuDir">
    <Condition><![CDATA[(VARIANT <> "OPC") OR (VARIANT <> "LOGGER")]]></Condition>
    <Shortcut Id="AlarmShortcut" Directory="ProgramMenuDir" Name="Alarm Monitor" Icon="almon_nt.exe" IconIndex="0" Target="[BIN]almon_nt.exe">
      <Icon Id="almon_nt.exe" SourceFile="$(var.Bin)\almon_nt.exe"/>
      <ShortcutProperty Key="System.AppUserModel.ExcludeFromShowInNewInstall" Value="1"/>
    </Shortcut>
    <RegistryValue Root='HKCU' Key='Software\ShortcutProperty\[PRODUCTNAME]' Type='string' Value='1' KeyPath='yes' Name='AlarmShortcut'/>
  </Component>

  <Component Id="UserAShortcut" Guid="328BB0A4-18CA-4E2A-9F6B-CEC81EF45B26" Directory="ProgramMenuDir">
    <Condition><![CDATA[(VARIANT <> "OPC") OR (VARIANT <> "LOGGER")]]></Condition>
    <Shortcut Id="UserAShortcut" Directory="ProgramMenuDir" Name="User Analogs" Icon="usera_cf.exe" IconIndex="0" Target="[BIN]usera_cf.exe">
      <Icon Id="usera_cf.exe" SourceFile="$(var.Bin)\usera_cf.exe"/>
      <ShortcutProperty Key="System.AppUserModel.ExcludeFromShowInNewInstall" Value="1"/>
    </Shortcut>
    <RegistryValue Root='HKCU' Key='Software\ShortcutProperty\[PRODUCTNAME]' Type='string' Value='1' KeyPath='yes' Name='UserAShortcut'/>
  </Component>
```

However the conditions always are true even when `VARIANT = LOGGER` and I don't know what the problem is.

The property is declared like: `<Property Id="VARIANT" Secure="yes"/>`
Anyone know why this is not working? Ive looked in the verbose log and the VARIANT property is not changing anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you are aiming to do then you should change

```
(VARIANT <> "OPC") OR (VARIANT <> "LOGGER")
```

to be

```
(VARIANT <> "OPC") AND (VARIANT <> "LOGGER")
```

At the moment, if VARIANT is LOGGER then the left side of the `OR` is returning true and the right is returning false, so the `OR` statement returns true, whereas it sounds like you only want it to return true if VARIANT is neither OPC nor LOGGER.